# Error: C2228: left of '' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm a long time Java user learning C++ with Qt and I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how methods work. Right now, I'm trying to figure out databases, and tried to simplify my code with a header. Normally in Java I would just have a class called DatabaseControl with a void method that would execute whatever I wanted. For example, adding an employee to a database, as I'm doing now. I'd instantiate the class, by doing something like

```
DatabaseControl myDBControl = new DatabaseControl();
```

and then execute the method with

```
myDBControl.addEmploye();
```

which would bring up the series of input boxes for the user to input the information on the employee - name, department, etc.

So, now over to C++. I have my header

```
class DatabaseControl
{
public:
    DatabaseControl();
    ~DatabaseControl();

    //Methods
    void addEmployee();
};
```

I don't have any parameters in my constructors because all I want to do is call the "addEmployee" method in my main as I've shown above. In the same header file I have this below my class declaration

```
void DatabaseControl::addEmployee(){
QSqlQuery qry;
bool ok;
QString firstName = QInputDialog::getText(NULL, "QInputDialog::getText()",
                                     "Employee first name:", QLineEdit::Normal,
                                     NULL, &ok);
if (ok && !firstName.isEmpty()){}
else{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
    msgBox.setText("Failed to add employee.\nReason: No employee name given.");
    msgBox.exec();
}
QString lastName = QInputDialog::getText(NULL, "QInputDialog::getText()",
                                     "Employee last name:", QLineEdit::Normal,
                                     NULL, &ok);
     if (ok && !lastName.isEmpty()){
         qry.prepare("INSERT INTO employees (firstname, lastname)" "VALUES (:f1, :f2)");
         qry.bindValue(":f1", firstName);
         qry.bindValue(":f2", lastName);
         qry.exec();
     }
     else{
         QMessageBox msgBox;
         msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
         msgBox.setText("Failed to add employee.\nReason: No employee name given.");
         msgBox.exec();
     }
```

}

and then in my main I have this:

```
void MainWindow::on_addEmployee_clicked()
{
    DatabaseControl myDBControl();
    myDBControl.addEmployee();
}
```

which I expected to just run the addEmployee method I wrote in the header file. However, when I compile, I get the error Error: C2228: left of '.addEmployee' must have class/struct/union

I've looked at other instances of this error and don't really understand exactly what's wrong, and I feel it comes from my misunderstanding of methods in C++, because I know in Java something like this would work without issue (assuming the code in the header is correct which it very well may not be)

Comment: @Lighthat: That's not an efficient or productive way of learning a language. Do it systematically. (Although you're eclipsed by some other guy a few days ago who noticed that both Python and C++ have a keyword `int` and was furious that it didn't do the same thing in both languages.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I [wouldn't say he was "furious"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20850645/560648), exactly...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: This is not the most vexing parse, though it is related.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not after your edit :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: Haha I'd forgotten about that

Comment: The reason I asked it with a reference to Java is to explain exactly what I was trying to do because I wasn't sure if I was wording it correctly, and I wanted to see how to do the same thing (or something similar) in C++, I never claimed that Java and C++ are similar.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You made an error here:

```
DatabaseControl myDBControl();
```

You declared a function called `myDBControl` taking no arguments and returning a `DatabaseControl`.

Object declarations without any constructor arguments must omit the `()`:

```
DatabaseControl myDBControl;
```

This is related to (but is not precisely) the "[most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)", in that it's caused by the same language rule that *statements are function declarations if they can be so parsed*.

Answer (score 2):

```
DatabaseControl myDBControl();
```

should be

```
DatabaseControl myDBControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say this:

```
 DatabaseControl myDBControl;
 myDBControl.addEmployee();
```

Answer (score 1):

In support to the accepted answer.

From [dcl.init#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#11):

An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., `()`, shall be value-initialized.

> [ Note: Since `()` is not permitted by the syntax for initializer,
>
> ```
> X a();
> ```
>
> is not the declaration of an object of `class X`, but the
>   **declaration of a function taking no argument and returning an X**. The form `()` is permitted in certain other initialization contexts
>   ([expr.new], [expr.type.conv], [class.base.init]). — end note ]